# Using SharePoint web services, how to access site configured for SAML token based authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, saml

As per this link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288475(v=office.14).aspx),
broadly I can configure any SharePoint site(2010/2013) using 3 types of authentication methods:

1. Windows authentication
2. Form based authentication
3. SAML token-based authentication

After googling I could find out ways to authenticate **using SharePoint web services** if my site is using Windows or Form based authentication(by setting up username and password in request headers and using authentication.asmx respectively) but could not find how to access a site configured with SAML token-based authentication using SharePoint web services. Can anybody throw some light on it or provide some link?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  If so, would you mind answering with your findings?

Comment: Very soon, I will start working on it, will definitly share my findings